# PHP to SQL Server connection

Tags: php, sql-server

I want to connect to a **SQL Server 2000** from **PHP** installed in a unix platform (**CentOs**) and to be able to run queries (SELECT and UPDATE). The solution must support **UTF-8** data.

As search through the web, I find out that there exists many different approaches (freeTDS, unixODBC, ODBTP, Easysoft ODBC, Easysoft ODBC-ODBC Bridge, PDO).

Could someone point me to the best solution for the specific connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that PDO_DBLIB was (and still is) experimental discourage me from using it. I decided to start testing a solution using freeTDS, that seemed to be the simpliest method. It turned out to function excellent, for that specific connection's case and I implemented the final application using it.

Answer (score 1):

`PDO` is the preferred library a.t.m, with `PDO_DBLIB` (at least, for Linux), see [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php). if you need it portable between Linux & Windows, use `PDO_ODBC.`

Comment: Sorry for the downvote, but noticed your comment was from 2010 and with MSSQL - PDO is experimental for MSSQL at the moment in 2012.

Comment: @Duniyadnd: afaik, it is still the preferred method. If you know a better / more preferred one please post the details to that as an answer.